# Dragon Priest Mask Displays in Player Homes bug out

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently switched from Skyrim to Skyrim Special Edition.
In my player homes (both modded and from the Creation Club) that have a Dragon Mask display, the Dragon Masks from the Dragonborn DLC (excluding Miraak's) are flipped sideways. When I place Vokun's mask on the display, it will get removed from my inventory, but then completely disappears.
It would be great to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: We really need more information than this. Especially, what mods do you use?